# FOSUserBundle validation form: display properly the validation strings

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

I realize this is really a newbie problem.

I simply don't understand how to "catch" the validation messages (e.g. "username already exist") and display it properly instead of how they come displayed by default.

I cannot post a picture, so here goes a copy paste:

Email: [here I can see email field]

- The email is already used

Username: [here I can see the username field]

- The username is already used

Password: [here I can see the pwd field]

Verification: [here I can see the pwd verification field]

Name: [here I can see the name field which I added]

I'd like to be able to catch those messages and maybe display little "popups" just aside the the name field, or do whatever else I like (but not showing them like that).

My code is the following:

This is the overridden register.html.twig

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %} {% block
fos_user_content %} This is my registration form <br> {% include
"FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %} {% endblock
fos_user_content %}
```

This is the register_content.html.twig (untouched)

```
 {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %} <form action="{{
 path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }}
 method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
     <div>
         <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
     </div> </form>
```

here is the overridden registrationFormType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I simply had to read the section on forms and how to manage their errors.

EDITED:
I had to change the register_content.html.twig as follows:

> ```
> {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
>
> <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST"
> class="fos_user_registration_register">
>     {{ form_errors(form) }}
>     <div>
>         {{ form_label(form.email) }}
>         {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
>         {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
>     </div>
>     <div>
>         {{ form_label(form.username) }}
>         {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
>         {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
>     </div>
>     <div>
>         {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
>         {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
>         {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
>     </div>
>     <div>
>         {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
>         {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
>         {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
>     </div>
>     <div>
>         {{ form_label(form.name) }}
>         {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
>         {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
>     </div>
>         {{ form_rest(form) }}
>     <div>
>         <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
>     </div>
> </form>
> ```

Comment: The Symfony documentation is very thorough.  Can you post what the solution was for you as your answer?

Comment: I edited my answer to post which was my solution @Jason Roman .